# Systemd service | Как обновлять файл демона, без необходимости останавливать процесс?

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, процесс

К примеру, есть вот такой service файл:

```
[Unit]
Description=App name
After=syslog.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/app
ExecStart=/home/user/app/app
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=app-name
User=user
Group=user
LimitNOFILE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Исполняемый файл: **/home/user/app/app**

Сейчас система не разрешит перезаписать файл, пока процесс запущен.
Нужно делать **systemctl stop**, **systemctl start**.

Возможно сделать конфигурацию, которая позволит заменять исполняемый файл и потом делать **systemctl restart**?

Comment: *Сейчас система не разрешит перезаписать файл, пока процесс запущен* — приведите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса ваши действия по «перезаписи файла» и реакцию на них «системы».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В linux нет блокировки перезаписи файла.

После того, как ваше приложение было запущено, вы можете удалить исполняемый файл или перезаписать его, при этом процесс продолжнить работать с "той" версией файла, а после перезапуска - с новой.

Поэтому вы можете смело копировать новую версию файла поверх старой и делать:

```
systemctl restart app
```